# Como cambiar una columna de una fabla reutilizando los demás valores

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Hola soy nuevo en `vuex js` y tengo la siguiente situación, tengo 2 tablas donde la primer columna de una es provincia y la de la otra ciudad, despues las siguientes columnas de las tablas corresponde con la cantidad de varones y mujeres que hay para una determinada ciudad o para una determinada provincia. Quería saber si se puede por medio de algún condicional o flag que me muestre una u otra columna dependiendo del caso.

```
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="rows" variable="1">
            <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
                <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.provincia }}</td> //<td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.ciudad }}</td>
                <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.varones}}</td>
                <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.mujeres }}</td>
            </template>
        </v-data-table>
```

Comment: Cual seria la condicion para mostrar una o la otra?

Comment: que la variable este en 1 o 0

Comment: La variable `provincia` y `ciudad`?

Comment: uso un flag llamado variable que si esta en 0 muestra provincia o 1 ciudad

Comment: Ese flag esta dentro del modelo?

Comment: no no el modelo solo tiene la tabla con esas variables

Comment: Considera agregar esa variable al modelo.  De esa forma pudes usar `v-if` https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html

Comment: muchas gracias!